# Why the documents (that have further sub collection) size is 0 when you call .collection("collName"). get()?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a similar problem as this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614242/why-is-firestore-documentsnapshot-data-size-always-zero), but no one has answered yet.  I have a collection that has documents and those documents have further collections. When I try to get these documents I receive 0 documents. [database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCsZO.png)

Code

```
db.collection("teachers").document("irfany").collection("OpenAssignments").
        get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d("getdocumentSize", task.getResult().size() + " => ");

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

            }
        } else {
            Log.d("Error", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

**Output**  D/getdocumentSize: 0 =>

Comment: The document seems to be empty ie. doesn't exist (but maybe has a sub-collection). Try adding a field in it and it should so up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but If you look into the image provided inquestion "Database Image "there is the document in it.

Comment: The document ID is italic that indicates it's empty/inexistent.

Comment: You are absolutely right, i have created another document and i fetched the document. Thanks

Comment: and idk why its in italic ... but yeah problem solved.

Comment: Shouldn't your comment be an answer, @Dharmaraj?

Comment: Why did you delete this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73426102/why-creating-multiple-documents-at-same-time-with-subcollection-appear-as-italic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Math 101` document in the provided screenshot *does not exist* (as indicated by the italic document ID) but there's a sub collection `assignmentData` in it. If you still want to query all document in `OpenAssignments` then it'll be best to add a field in the document to actually create it.

If your goal is to query `assignmentData` documents of all OpenAssignments then you can use a [Collection Group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) query instead.

Also checkout: [Firestore query returns no documents even though they are shown in the console in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70539221/13130697)

Comment: In short, it's just a holder for the sub-collection that exists under it.